# For a group $G$, let $a,b$ be arbitrary elements in $G$, if $a^{n}b^{n-1} = b^{n-1}a^{n}$ for all integers $n$, does this imply $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> For a group $G$ with arbitrary elements $a,b$, if $a^{n}b^{n-1} = b^{n-1}a^{n}$ for all integers $n$, does this imply $G$ is abelian?

I've tried solving for $b$ and $b^{-1}$ explicitly, and I have tried working backwards from $ab=ba$. So far I am stumped.

Comment: To be clear: this is supposed to be true for all choices of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: This is true for all $a,b$

Comment: I was trying to write a test question for my students for a makeup exam. The original question I posed for them was to prove $G$ is abelian iff $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$ for all $a,b$ in $G$, for $n \geq 2$. I modified $n$ slightly, to see if I could write a question with a similar difficultly, but I cannot seem to prove it offhand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that the property is true "for all integers $n$" iff it is true for $n=2,$ i.e. iff every square is in the center.

This property does not imply abelianity. A counterexample is the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).

Comment: How come you can use the first "iff"?

Comment: Noticing this "iff" helped me to find the counterexample, but I don't *need* to use it.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't answer my question; I'm wondering what justifies the "iff".

Comment: $n,n-1$ are different parity. If $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ is even, and we can break $b^{n-1}$ into a product of $b^2$ terms, each of which commute with the $a^n$. If $n$ is even, we break up the $a^n$ terms instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This answers my question!

Comment: Oh, I understood you were asking "how does it come that you can use it". Well: if every square is in the center then for every $n>1,$ either $n$ or $n-1$ is even hence either $a^n$ or $b^{n-1}$ is a square, thus commuting with the other one.

Comment: I see! Thank you! I have already upvoted. Thank you, especially, because for a while I thought I could prove $G$ is abelian and was in the middle of a monster of a "proof" when I saw your answer . . .